# Import particular nodes into Neo4J from CSV file

Tags: import, neo4j, cypher, load-csv

I'm doing some tests in order to figure out how to best import data from a CSV file into Neo4J. I have the following data in the Person.csv file (3 headers, Person_ID, Name, and Type):

```
Person_ID       Name    Type
HUA001          Jaap    Layperson
HUA002          Teems   Priest
HUA003          Frank   Layperson
```

I want to import the nodes which are of a particular type (e.g. 'Layperson').

I thought about creating a LOAD CSV command with a WHERE statement (see below), but Neo4J doesn't particularly like that WHERE statement. Any ideas how to get this (or a query with a similar result) working?

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Person.csv' AS row 
WHERE row.Type='Layperson' 
CREATE (p:Person:Layperson {ID: row.Person_ID, name: row.Name})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`WITH`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/with/) and `WHERE` combined to filter the required rows and pass on the filtered rows to the next query which creates the nodes.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Person.csv' AS row 
WITH row
WHERE row.Type='Layperson'
CREATE (p:Person:Layperson {ID: row.Person_ID, name: row.Name})
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Didn't know that a 'WITH' statement would be necessary.